# Google App Engine won't update content on edit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, windows-7

I'm having this weird problem where when I run an app on GAE locally on Windows 7. Everything works fine except when I update the code; It works well the first 10 minutes and then it doesn't update when I edit the code. I have to close the server and open it again.
It's not a cache problem, because even if I try it in a different browser the content still doesn't change.

I tried reinstalling python and appengine and it worked fine for 2 days, but then problem came back again. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you debugging?  Won't update if you break in the debugger.

Comment: i don't think i understand what do you mean ? i'am developing the projects from the udacity lessons, so i'am always editing and refreshing the browser to see changes, whats weird is it works fine for sometime, than it doesn't.
also it;s all locally, nothing is hosted

Comment: Specifically what isn't updating? Are you changing code, adding handlers, modifying app.yaml?

Comment: i'am editing code in the main.py
say for example the hello world.
if i modify the string Hello world, save , refresh the page, it works, 
but only for a while, later it wouldn't change the website when i modify the string.

Comment: There's an open issue for this, please star it! http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8383

Answer (score 1):

Since your issue is limited to Python files, it sounds like a bug that was brought up in the [discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/EdM10tC9JH4/94vsByWgG_8J) and [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8397).

The suggested workaround in the forum is to remove the `.pyc` files corresponding the `.py` file you are editing, restart the local server, and continue. Obviously this is sub-optimal, so I would suggest 'starring' the bug in the issue tracker to keep track of updates.

Comment: Thanks, starred the bug, restarting the local server without deleting .pyc works for a few minutes, but i will try deleting .pyc to see if that help. i hope there is a fix soon.